# Atlassian Sourcetree + GIT + Mac + Mountain Lion + Eclipse + Android project = failure mode

Tags: eclipse, git, macos, osx-mountain-lion, atlassian-sourcetree

Using the combination of tools in the title, when I check out a branch, SourceTree/GIT will:

1. Definitely NOT delete folders from the previously checked-out branch, so if I have BRANCH-ALPHA with FOLDER1 and FOLDER2 and then I check out BRANCH-BETA which has FOLDER2 and FOLDER3 only and no FOLDER1, the resulting structure in FINDER will show that FOLDER1 is still there.  Can reproduce this over and over.
2. Often will not even overwrite files from the previously checked-out branch, so that I'm still seeing BRANCH-ALPHA in Eclipse when I have checked-out BRANCH-BETA.

I close Eclipse before doing the checkout, and then open Eclipse, CLEAN and BUILD everything.  It's really a problem with GIT.

The only "solution" is to delete all the folders and all the metadata and then check out the branch.  This typically leads to a few hours of trying to "convince" Eclipse to open the project, creating a new workspace, new metadata, etc., and then fixing a lot of things like paths etc.

Any ideas on how to further research the cause and find a solution are very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure **FOLDER1** has been committed in BRANCH-ALPHA?

Answer (score 0):

Git only deletes **empty** folders when checking out a new commit. You might see apparently empty directories because there are hidden files stored in them. If you try to monitor the behavior by opening them in Finder, you're actually causing the problem since Finder creates hidden files to track the way the folders are displayed.

Does it really bother you that the folders are there? You could add a [post-checkout hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_checkout) that runs `git clean -dxf` after each checkout; this will remove all the files that are not known by git. Be careful that it will also delete compiled classes, so a new build will be required.

Another possibility is that something is locking files or directories, so git can't remove them while they're still opened/locked by the other program. This would also explain why some files aren't updated to the right version. Does git complain when you switch branches? It should if there's indeed a lock on the files.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in on this...  it seems that on objective-c / xcode projects, GIT will delete folders that are not part of the branch you are checking out...  GIT isn't complaining, and I always completely close Eclipse before checking out a branch, but it is possible that the files have some kind of read-only permission set by Eclipse on the OSX filesystem.  My expectation for a VCS is that after checking out a branch, the filesystem should EXACTLY match what was checked out, except for .ignore'd files and folders of course.  Which reminds me to check the global .ignore on this issue...